# how to get the date of a file on the server with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a static page that does not use any server-side scripting and would like to grab the date a file was last modified (or created) with an ajax request using javascript or jquery. Is this possible?

Comment: Where is this file located?

Comment: Which web server are you on?

Comment: The file would be in a subfolder of the page with the ajax on it. I'm trying to make this universal, so the server shouldn't matter so long as the files are all under the same root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. In order to access the file on a server, you need some sort of server-side scripting

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to grab the information for a file hosted with some third-party service and you have access to their API, then you can send them an ajax request. Of course this is assuming their API allows you to request that information on a file.

Comment: no API, strictly a local file under the same folder as the script.

Comment: Just the usual date modified, size, type and rights I see in Linux when I look at it through ftp or ssh. I'm assuming that data is not actually attached to the file itself but part of the Linux system, or?

Comment: I don't it can be accessed outside of ftp

Comment: Maybe if you were to give more details about your exact situation, it would be easier to come up with a solution. How do you have access to the server, but not the ability to run apache on it?